# How do I get the column names for the keys in a DataFrameGroupBy object?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a grouped DataFrame (obtained by `df.groupby([col1, col2])`) I would like to obtain the grouping variables (`col1` and `col2` in this case).

For example, from the [GroupBy user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("bird", "Falconiformes", 389.0),
        ("bird", "Psittaciformes", 24.0),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 80.2),
        ("mammal", "Primates", np.nan),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 58),
    ],
    index=["falcon", "parrot", "lion", "monkey", "leopard"],
    columns=("class", "order", "max_speed"),
)
grouped = df.groupby(["class", "order"])
```

Given `grouped` I would like to get `class` and `order`. However, `grouped.indices` and `grouped.groups` contain only the values of the keys, not the column names.

The column names must be in the object somewhere, because if I run `grouped.size()` for example, they are included in the indices:

```
class   order         
bird    Falconiformes     1
        Psittaciformes    1
mammal  Carnivora         2
        Primates          1
dtype: int64
```

And therefore I can run `grouped.size().index.names` which returns `FrozenList(['class', 'order'])`. But this is doing an unnecessary calculation of `.size()`. Is there a nicer way of retrieving these from the object?

The ultimate reason I'd like this is so that I can do some processing for a particular group, and associate it with a key-value pair which defines the group. That way I would be able to amalgamate different grouped datasets with arbitrary levels of grouping. For example I could have

```
group                            max_speed
class=bird,order=Falconiformes       389.0
class=bird,order=Psittaciformes       24.0
class=bird                           206.5
foo=bar                               45.5
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to your own suggestion, you can extract the grouped by column names using:

```
grouped.dtypes.index.names
```

It is not shorter, but you avoid calling a method.

Answer (score 1):

Grouped DataFrame (obtained by df.groupby([col1, col2])) is converted to pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy- Object. So we have to convert it into DataFrame in order to get the column names.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(grouped.size().reset_index(name = "Group_Count"))
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    class           order  Group_Count
0    bird   Falconiformes            1
1    bird  Psittaciformes            1
2  mammal       Carnivora            2
3  mammal        Primates            1
```

```
print(df2.info())
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 
 0   class        4 non-null      object
 1   order        4 non-null      object
 2   Group_Count  4 non-null      int64 
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 224.0+ bytes
```

I think this would solve your problem of selecting the column names from the grouped data. The function `DataFrame.groupBy(cols)` returns a GroupedData object. In order to convert a GroupedData object back to a DataFrame, you will need to use one of the GroupedData functions such as `mean(cols) avg(cols) count()`.